# Interesting tangents problems

Tags: calculus

My question is simple. I'm teaching Calculus 1 and I'm looking for counterintuitive problems to find tangents. I want to show to my students the importance of the limit definition of tangents.

Thanks

**EDIT (Clarification)**

I'm looking for tangents which may mislead students. The students think the tangent is a line $A$, but in fact the tangent is another line $B$.

Comment: Tangents to curves?

Comment: @Narasimham yes

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by counter-intuitive problems.

Comment: @G-man I'm looking for tangents which may mislead students. The students think the tangent is a line $A$, but in fact the tangent is another line $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following function $f(x)$
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
      1-x^2 & x\neq0\\
      2 & x=0  
\end{array} $$
Looking at the graph one might think that at the point $x=0$, the tangent is $y-1=0$, but in fact by limit definition it should be the Y-axis.

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's exactly I was looking for!

Comment: The function is not derivable at this point, can I say there is a tangent at $x=0$?

Comment: @user42912  Geometrically speaking I think the tangent should exist but calculus will disagree.